# Command not working anymore in Thunar custom actions

Tags: command, conversion, thunar, multimedia

I used to create a Thunar custom action as presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/294426/47206) in order to extract audio  without transcoding from selected (multiple) video files .

The command to be added in Thunar custom actions list was:

```
 xfce4-terminal -e "parallel avconv -i '{}' -map 0:1 -c:a copy '{}.m4a' -- %F"
```

now I get only this:

```
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.
```

Why is that and how to adapt such commands so that they would work in 
Thunar custom actions?

Comment: As i understand, it's just a warning not an error, does it work as it's should?

Comment: @kirill-a : no, it does not; nothing happens, and the only option seems the CTRL-D to exit terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand that command. Why do you put -- before the %F?

Try this:

```
xfce4-terminal -e "parallel avconv -i '{}' -map 0:1 -c:a copy '{}.m4a' ::: %F"
```

Explanation: As I understand the %F is what Thunar replaces by the files, and parallel uses ::: for the input.

One example in the manpage is, precisely

```
parallel gzip {} ::: file1 file2
```

---

To add to Thunar custom action a command like the one from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/235912/47206)

```
for i in *.mp4; do avconv -i "${i}" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${i%.mp4}.aac"; done
```

first add that into an executable script, like

```
#! /bin/sh -e
for i in *.mp4; do avconv -i "${i}" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${i%.mp4}.m4a"; done
```

Make it executable and save it.

In Thunar custom actions add a new entry with the command `bash /path/to/the/script %F` and the following conditions:

[image]

This needs separate custom actions for each file type (because it is limited to mp4 to m4a: make changes accordingly for flv to m4a, webm to ogg, avi to mp3 etc) but has the advantage that the output keeps the exact input name (*file.mp4* becomes *file.m4a*), while with the first command does not (*file.mp4* becomes *file.mp4.m4a*).

Comment: It is too odd. Try this: in a console, go to a folder with at least two mp4 files and do `xfce4-terminal -e "parallel avconv -i '{}' -map 0:1 -c:a copy '{}.m4a' ::: file1.mp4 file2.mp4"` (replacing file1 and file2 for the actual files). Does it work?

Comment: my error. i will re-edit everything, your answer is correct

Comment: another advantage of the last solution is that it doesn't need `parallel` to be installed

Comment: Great! And thanks for completing my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What I use now is this:

```
bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".m4a' %f
```

with setting `*.flv;*.mp4` for appearance conditions.