# Extract audio from video without conversion in Thunar custom actions

Tags: xfce, command, thunar

Thunar custom actions can be used to convert media files by adding a simple command like

```
avconv -i %f %f.mp3
```

I would like a command to extract aac sound from mp4 and flv files with a Thunar custom action, just extract the  aac eventually in a m4a container, without conversion, similar to [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/235912/47206) (which I do not know how to adapt for Thunar custom actions):

```
for i in *.mp4; do avconv -i "${i}" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${i%.mp4}.aac"; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a more general question about this: [Command not working anymore in Thunar custom actions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176775/32012) and I have received [a good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180324/32012). I have edited to extend that answer and cover this question too.

The command mentioned in the question needs to be added to a script which then can be run from Thunar:

```
#! /bin/sh -e
for i in *.mp4; do avconv -i "${i}" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${i%.mp4}.m4a"; done
```

A simpler command also works:

```
avconv -i %f -map 0:1 -c:a copy %f.m4a
```

which is just a modification of

```
avconv -i %f %f.mp3
```

---

### Update: improved command

`ffmpeg` can be used instead of `avconv`

And add this to Thunar custom actions;

```
bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".m4a' %f
```

setting `*.flv;*.mp4` for appearance conditions.

(for `webm` video replace with `ogg`, use `mediainfo` to get info on the audio stream of the video).

Source of the above [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/288571/47206) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229626/32012).